# Using jQuery .on() on LI elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am having some difficulty with getting jQuery .on() to work. It currently seems fine with h1 elements, as in the first '.on()', but it doesn't want to work when I use an li element, when I include it either as a class, id, or even simple element. Using an ID isn't possible for what I want to do, as I have a couple of hundred elements that I want this bound to each with a different numerical ID.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //a h1 element
    $('#title').on('click',function(){ //works
        console.log("clicked");
    });

    //li elements, don't work
    $('#56813XXXX').on('click',function(){ //doesn't work
        console.log("clicked");
    });
    $('li').on('click',function(){ //doesn't work
        console.log("clicked");
    });
    $('.listItem').on('click',function(){ // doesn't work
        console.log("clicked");
    });
})
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<ul id="friendsList">
    <li id="56813XXXX" class="listItem">Text</li>
    <li id="56095XXXX" class="listItem">Text</li>
    <--several hundred more elements-->
</ul>
```

So any idea how to get it working for li elements?

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  I think you're going to have to get more specific about your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/fpLP8/ -- also `'56813XXXX'` is not a valid element

Comment: yes, an example of the markup would be interesting, is there possibly anything in the list-elements that prevents the event from bubbling?

Comment: Just put the markup in, fixed that element - it was meant to be an ID.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gsKGS/ your code is working for me...

Comment: Works for me to, and ID should'nt generally contain only numbers, and using XXX does'nt do what you seem to think it does ?

Comment: it's working for me  here with your code only :http://jsfiddle.net/eN8Uf/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MK7N8/ it's working here. Maybe there's an issue.. since the response of jsFidle is only based on the last function (.listItem) the others are ignore / overwritten

Comment: Hmm, it is working for me on jsFiddle too... :/ Why can't ids contain only numbers? In this context it's specifically so that the ID can be passed to a function and needs to be a number. I'm only using XXXX to obscure Facebook IDs (which I just realised I didn't do for the markup!

Comment: Just prepend them with 'fb' or something. Also, if this is working for everyone else and still not you... Are you dynamically loading these elements into the DOM?

Comment: No, all those jsFiddles do work for me too, it's just not working in my app. Either way, doing it the way suggested in the answer that I accepted does work. Thanks for the help everyone! :)

Comment: @CodeO'Clock your original code was binding the events to elements that did not exist yet. Your list items are populated dynamically via AJAX. The accepted answer works because the event is bound to the parent `<ul>` which _does_ exist when the JavaScript is executed. The click is captured by the `<ul>` and [delegated](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) to the correct `li`.

Comment: @andyb that wasn't it I'm afraid, I tried moving those `.on()` statements to a part of the javascript that ends after that `<ul>` is populated. I even tried using `.live()` instead in `$(document).ready` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are the `<li>` being generated from AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this? It will scope the calls the to parent `<ul>` and bind the click event to any `<li>` elements that are added dynamically.

```
$('#friendsList').on('click', 'li', function() { 
     console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: `$('li', $('#friendlist')).on('click', function() { } );` would be another way to write this.

Comment: Sure that this will have the same effect?